# Why are decodeAudioData() results different on different OS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, operating-system, web-audio-api

**Update 2:** Run the script here. It will show the sample rate when clicking the "LOAD" button.

```js
function decode() {
    // If the default naming is not enabled, use the Chrome one
    if (!window.AudioContext) {
        if (!window.webkitAudioContext) {
            alert("No AudioContext found.");
        }
        window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
    }
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    alert("sample rate: " + audioContext.sampleRate);
    var sourceNode;

    var BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    // Create buffer node and download file to buffer
    createAudioNodes();
    var fileURL = "http://plaay.in/decode-audio-data/decode-this-audio.wav";
    downloadAudioFromURL(fileURL);

    function createAudioNodes() {
        sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    }

    function downloadAudioFromURL(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);

        request.onload = function() {
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
                setSourceBuffer(buffer);
            }, onError);
        };
        request.send();
    }

    function updateProgress(progress) {
        if (progress.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "Loading... " + percentComplete.toString() + "%";
        }
    }

    function setSourceBuffer(buffer) {
        var leftInBuffer = buffer.getChannelData(0);
        console.log("leftInBuffer length: " + leftInBuffer.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < leftInBuffer.length; i++) {
            console.log(leftInBuffer[i]);
        }
    }

    function onError(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Decode Audio Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="decode.js"></script>
    <button id="playButton" type="button" style="height:40px;width:150px" onclick="decode()">LOAD</button>
    <p id="progress">File download progress</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update**: filed an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=569036).

I want to decode an audio file and get its raw data for processing in the following step. The idea is to use [decodeAudioData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData) of Web Audio API. The weird problem is the decode results will depend on the operating system. Did anyone encounter the same problem, or know the reason why?

I made a quick [demo](http://plaay.in/decode-audio-data/decode.html) and tested it on Mac OS (10.11) and Windows 7 and the browsers are both Chrome (v46.0+), but their results are different. To visualize the results:

[image]

Everyone can run this [demo](http://plaay.in/decode-audio-data/decode.html), just click the "LOAD" button and the results will be logged in the console.

Comment: I figure Raymond is about as official a source you're going to find as he's a part of the Web Audio W3C group and a Googler working on the Web Audio API. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) can set the sample rate for my later `decodeAudioData()`. To decode a 30 seconds long stereo audio with 44.1kHz sample rate, create an `offlineAudioContext` like the following, and don't forget `webkit` prefix for Safari.

```
window.OfflineAudioContext = window.offlineAudioContext || window.webkitOfflineAudioContext;
var offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(2, 44100 * 30, 44100);
```

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't be different between Windows and Chrome.  File a bug at [crbug.com/new](http://crbug.com/new).

Comment: You are right. On Mac, the sample rate is 44100, whereas on Windows, the sample rate is 48000. And I realized the sampleRate is a readonly property (set by the OS and browsers?). That will bring some difficulties for my following audio processing because the audio samples are totally different. Any suggestions?

Comment: And I'm also curious of why the default sample rate on Windows is 48000 Hz.

Comment: I do not know how Windows sets the default.  But you can change the default sample rate for the builtin audio devices.  Do you really need to have exactly the same length everywhere?

Comment: Is the built in audio device related to the browser or the OS? And what specification should I refer to? Since my algorithm will calculate the interval between the samples, so I want to keep the same sample rate if possible.

Comment: WebAudio queries the OS for the sample rate and uses whatever it says.  You might also be interested in this [WebAudio spec issue](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/30), but that won't be resolved until the next version of the spec.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and looks like several workarounds worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser / operating system combination can use a different decoder library, and each decoder can have slightly different results due to ambiguities in the standards. It's something that has bitten me too in the past and that one has to live with. Or use uncompressed formats!